# Google Places and Foursquare iOS API

Tags: ios, foursquare, google-places-api, google-places

I am creating an app that displays my business and my business only.

I've been able (with the help of Ray Wenderlich tutorial) to make it so that it displays locations by type, name etc...

I know it's not possible to search by **id** or **reference** which means I'm stuck with **name** and **keyword** search.

My questions:

a) How can I do a place search and be sure that it shows my business only (one or more results depending on the number of venues) and no business with a similar name?

For example: If I do a search by name for McDonalds it will return "McDonalds", "McDonalds House", "McDonalds Burger Joint" etc etc...

b) The following code:

```
-(void)plotPositions:(NSArray *)data {
      for (int i=0; i<[data count]; i++) {
           NSDictionary* place = [data objectAtIndex:i];
           NSString *name=[place objectForKey:@"name"];
               if ([name isEqualToString:@"McDonalds"]{
                   [mapView addAnnotation:placeObject];
               }
  }
```

works for what I'm looking for, I think.
But if, for some reason, there are 2 or more businesses called "McDonalds" it will display them all.
Is there a way to get over this using the Google Places API?

c)Does the Foursquare API allow any of this?

Thank you!

Comment: Since you know your business, shouldn't you know what to look for?

Comment: Yes, but what if there's 2 businesses with my name in the same area? How will I be able to display only mine?
Maybe I'm not approaching this correctly...

Comment: You could, for example, look at the location of the place. I don't know what the google places API returns exactly, but there must be some more stuff than just the name in there (location would definitely be one since you can put it on a map view)

Comment: As an aside, why even use google places api? You know your business and the info you want to display, so why not just do it?

Comment: the reason for using the API was so it was "connected" to my Google Business page directly... But your question actually makes sense... I could create a location and info and leave the api out of it.

Comment: Well, you can use the API. Since you know at what coordinates your business is, you can just use that to find the right one. Simply select the one that's closes to the real location and matches the name. I guess you aren't moving around every few weeks?

Comment: I guess... I think I am making it more difficult than it really is...
Thank you! This helped me ;)
Is there a way to vote up any of your comments?

Comment: I've put my comments together in an answer, so you aren't left with a question without an answer and just a bunch of comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to stick to the google places API, you can combine multiple properties that you know about your business to narrow the list of returned places down. The best bet for this would probably name + location, since the location should be already pretty unique and known beforehand, since it's your business. I would suggest looking for the name and then picking the one that is closest to the actual location, but no farther away than `x`, just in case google places fails and doesn't return your business.

Which brings me to another point, since it's your business and you know all the info, maybe you could provide it from your own server instead of relying on google? You could, for example, have a static `plist` on your server with all the information you need. This way you can update it when you need to (for example new phone number or something like that).

Comment: Thank you! Doing it on my own server...makes sense. Like I said, I was approaching it the wrong way.